# sNothing happens on ajax data submit in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm tryin to write a wordpress plugin who needs to query the db. I can't get it to work. This is what i tried:

```
jQuery('#demo_ajax').submit(function(){
    var data = jQuery("#data").val();
    $.ajax({ 
        data: data,
        type: 'post',
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>?action=demo_ajax',
    });
});
```

a simple form:

```
<form action="" id="demo_ajax" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="data" placeholder="Data" id="data">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

and the php handler:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_demo_ajax', 'demo_ajax' );
function demo_ajax() {
    echo '<script>alert("' . $_POST["data"] . '"</script>';
    die();
}
```

Now, when i click the submit button, nothing happens...the page is just reloaded (and it shouldn't...). Am i missing some code?

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the form from submitting, so use `return false;`

```
jQuery('#demo_ajax').submit(function(){
    var data = jQuery("#data").val();
    $.ajax({ 
        data: data,
        type: 'post',
        url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>?action=demo_ajax",
    });
    return false; //add this
});
```

Comment: Or `event.preventDefault()` instead return.

Comment: nothing to do: the page is still reloaded and the function is not being executed...